# The definition of Dirac function along a curve

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory

Take $\mathbb R^2$ as example, it is known that $\delta_{x_1=0}(\phi)=\int_{\mathbb R}\phi(0,x_2)dx_2$. What about $\delta_{x_2=x_1^2}$?

At the beginning I thought it should be integrated by arc length i.e. $\delta_{x_2=x_1^2}(\phi)=\int_{x_2=x_1^2}\phi(x_1,x_2)ds=\int_{\mathbb R}\phi(t,t^2)\sqrt{4t^2+1}dt$. But this definition does not preserve linear scaling.

Is there any best definition to characterize these Dirac function on a curve?

Comment: there are many "Dirac/distributions on a curve $\gamma$", all of the form $\varphi \mapsto \int_\gamma \varphi(x) d\mu(x)$ for some measure $\mu$ on the curve. Here you took the arclength measure, but you can use the $dx_2$ measure or whatever. And I don't see what you mean with "preserving linear scaling".

Comment: @user1952009 preserving scaling means that if we set $y=Ax$ then $\int_\gamma \phi(x)ds=\int_{A(\gamma)} \phi(A^{-1}y)ds$

Comment: I doesn't make sense, try with $\gamma$ a line segment, you need to divide the RHS by $\det(A)$ (if $A$ is a linear transformation)